# non-linear partial differential operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I am looking for some literature on non-linear partial differential operators used in geometry or analysis. Can you give me some reference. Thanks in advance.

eric

Answer (score 1):

One, by now, older text which may get you started:

Thierry Aubin: Some nonlinear problems in Riemannian Geometry